# Docker + supervisord: how to initialize services (mongo & elasticmq)?

Tags: mongodb, docker, supervisord

I am using docker with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to create tests environments with some services we use, as recommended in [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/). The basic configuration for the services is running, I can /bin/bash the container and use it from my application without problem (with some initialisation by hand)

Now I need to add some objects to mongo: basic data to test the applications. Is there a recommended way to do that? Using a bash script I would do:

```
...
# Launch Mongodb
/usr/bin/mongod &
sleep 3;
mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('MyDDBB').User.save( {...} )";
...
```

but that bash is what I'm trying to get rid of. The use of [elasticmq](https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq) is exactly the same: I need to run something that creates some queues when te container starts running, so probably one solution fits both.

I'm open to different solutions (change the supervisor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for a perfect solution, this might not be the one but it works for me:

In my docker-compose.yml I  set it so it uses my own entrypoint:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:2.4
    entrypoint: /code/devops/current/docker/dev/mongodb/entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
        - ~/Workspaces/project/devops/:/code/devops/current/
```

And my entrypoint first starts mongod in the background, execute a javascript file kill mongo and start it as the main process, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

mongod --noprealloc --smallfiles &
PID="$!"

echo "WAITING FOR INIT"
sleep 3

echo "--> init"
mongo /code/devops/current/docker/dev/mongodb/init.js
echo "--> init [DONE]"

kill $PID

echo "WAITING FOR KILL"
sleep 3

mongod --noprealloc --smallfiles --auth
```

In the init.js I make sure my tables are created, and have the user required to access it, so it's a bunch of:

```
db = db.getMongo().getDB('mydbname')
db.createCollection('mycollection')
db.addUser({user: "devuser", pwd: "mypassword", roles: ["readWrite"]})
```

So I imagine you have to adapt pretty much everything but it gets me going for my dev environment ;)